# Definition of nonarithmetic law

Tags: stochastic-processes, logarithm, arithmetic

I came across the term nonarithmetic, but I don't now what that means. It is a condition for a Proposition of a Paper I am reading. There it is said:

Assume that the law of $\ln A_0$ is nonarithmetic. ...

$A_0$ is here a random variable. What does it mean that the law of $\ln A_0$ is nonarithmetic?

Comment: Is this paper perhaps a translation?  Or was it written hundreds of years ago?  Could you provide more context to help us understand what it might mean?

Comment: It is from https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10986-005-0015-6.pdf Proposition 6 on page 381.

Comment: It is important to note that this article was published in an obscure journal likely edited and reviewed by non-native English speakers.  Without more information, one can only guess what was possibly meant.  Have you written the author?

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my question, I found a definition (https://books.google.de/books?id=WjulDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=Goldie/Kesten+theorem&source=bl&ots=d-3kR879Y8&sig=50qybYvPl0po_NblLPbyAEupm90&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLy6Gn4oDcAhWKyqYKHcHpAyoQ6AEITzAE#v=onepage&q=Goldie%2FKesten%20theorem&f=false) page 47

A random variable is nonarithmetic if it is not supported on any of the sets $a\mathbb{Z}$, $a \geq 0$.

So this means, that it is not something that takes values on a discrete grid of values.